# Unable to pass parameters to rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing the ransack demo app from [github](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack_demo). The app is using `rails 5.1.0.alpha`. Unfortunately, it appears this version of Rails is broken. I am unable to pass any parameters to the call `rails server`:

```
$ rails server -b 0.0.0.0
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ransack_demo/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/base.rb:484:in `handle_argument_error': ERROR: "rails server" was called with arguments ["-b", "0.0.0.0"] (Thor::InvocationError)
Usage: "bin/rails server [options]"
```

After doing some searching, I discovered this was a reported problem on the rails github account:

```
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26977
```

Apparently, `5.1.1.alpha` has a bug. I CANNOT use `rails 5.0.1` instead. The app I am using apparently uses an exclusive feature to the new alpha version:

```
<%= tag.h1 'Search Users' %>
```

That line of code will break on older versions of Rails.

I went to the Rails github repository and checked the `RAILS_VERSION` file. It states that the latest version is `5.1.0.alpha`. So I cannot upgrade to a newer version of Rails. Is there a ref or a git branch that I can update to?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the -b flag. what does that do?

Comment: @Brad none of the flags work. That's the point. When you call rails server with any flag it doesn't work. To answer your question, it is to bind to a specific address.

Comment: Since the `Gemfile.lock` says 5.0.1, did you try running `bundle install` afterwards?

Comment: @ma_il yes I ran bundle install. Hence, when 5.0.0.1 was installed.

Comment: @Brad  I updated my question

Comment: @ma_il check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get this to run quickly before the PR you referenced has been merged into upstream, you could directly point your `Gemfile` to the fork that the PR is based on.

Just change it to say:

```
gem `rails`, git: 'https://github.com/y-yagi/rails.git', branch: `fix_26964`
```

Comment: How can I determine on https://github.com/rails/rails which branch contains the fix?

Comment: The PR page you linked to in your question contains the forking users account name and the branch name. The repo name is the same as the original. Unfortunately they don't add a link.